Rest API to share the service connection in Azure DevOps Server 2019
I want to share the service endpoint with different project in AD Server 2019.
However, there is no API support available officially. Any one using share API. Kindly share with me.
TIA
I tried API version 6.0 and 5.0. However it is failed.

I checked with Azure developer community. There is no api for share the service endpoint in AD Server 2019.
Ticket link for reference https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/API-for-share-Service-endpoint-with-othe/10693203?space=21&q=share+service+endpoint+rest+api

yes. There is no api can achieve  this in AD Sever 2019. I have shared the info in the answer below. Please check if it can work for you.

I am afraid that there is no such Rest API/Feature can share the service endpoint in Azure DevOps Server 2019.
When you use Azure DevOps Server 2019, it doesn't support sharing the Service Connection.
Refer to Azure DevOps Server 2020 release note: Azure DevOps Server 2020 Release Notes

We plan to introduce Cross-project Sharing of Service Connections as a new capability. You can find more details about the sharing experience and the security roles here.

This feature is only available in Azure DevOps Server 2020 and later versions.
We can also confirm this in the REST API documentation: Endpoints - Share Service Endpoint. When we select the Azure DevOps Server 2019 version, it will redirect to the newest product version. This means that the Rest API doesn't support being used in Azure DevOps Server 2019.

To let more features available in Azure DevOps Server, I suggest that you can upgrade the Azure DevOps Server to the latest version: Azure DevOps Server 2022.
